# loading admob interstital ad when app launches using swift

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I'm looking to find away to load an admob interstitial ad when my app launches. Just load one initial ad when the app launches. I'm using swift and can't seem to find any forms on how to do this.

Comment: You can't handle it in _applicationDidFinishLaunching_?

Answer (score 0):

```
import GoogleMobileAds
```

In Appdelegate Create function

```
func createAndLoadAd() -> GADInterstitial
{
 var ad = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-5018462886395219/7896492088")

 var request = GADRequest()

 request.testDevices = ["2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9b"]
 ad.loadRequest(request)

 return ad
}
```

In DidFinishLunchingMethod

```
self.interstitial = self.createAndLoadAd()
if (self.interstitial.isReady)
{
 self.interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self)
 self.interstitial = self.createAndLoadAd()
}
```

Comment: This seems like its going to work. But I am getting a couple errors. first I have one on the var ad = GADInterstitial line that says " int() is unavailable. than on the next line that says cannot assign to adUnitID in ad.  than at the line in the second part on the line that says self.interstitial = self thats says "app delegate does not have a member named interstitial. and the same error on the next line.

Comment: okay the error for the first section are go but the code I put in the DidFinishLaunchingMethod still has an error. It's telling me to change the code to this "self.interstitial = self.createAndLoadAd()
        if (self.interstitial!.isReady)
        {
            self.interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self)
            self.interstitial = self.createAndLoadAd()
        }" But I get an error on the line that has presentFromRoot.. saying "Cannot invoke 'presentFromRootViewController with an argument list of type (appDelegate)'

Comment: I also had to add var interstitial: GADInterstital? to the ver beginning of my appDelegate to get the other error fixed.

Comment: any idea on how i can fix this?